# How to create a membership channel?

Tags: wordpress, telegram-bot

It's the first time that I used `Telegram Bot` and I'm looking for a way to create a membership channel, in particular:

I have a website where the users can subscribe a specific mebership level and this give access to a specific feature of the site. Actually I was able to create a bot and establish a communication with the site through the channel (where the bot is linked). In this way, each time that I publish an article on my `Wordpress` site the users of the `Telegram Channel` can see the article.

*The problem*

In this way, all the users of the cannel can see the article, I want show the message that contains the article only to the users which have subscribed a membership on my `WordPress` site. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a channel to your solution adds extra complexity. Suggested solution as your requirement:

1. Add [telegram web login](https://telegram.org/blog/login) to your website. After that you will have access to those users to send them a message via your bot.
2. Send your messages only to whom have an active subscription.
   This way you can also remind individual users in case of expiration of their subscription

Comment: there is a tutorial that I can follow?

Comment: This link would be a good starting point: https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/how-to-set-up-telegram-to-be-used-with-wordpress/

Comment: Well, as I said in my question I already configured wp with telegram with a similar system, actually I'm able to send the content of the latest article to all the users of my channel. The main problem is manage a different level of subscription on the telegram channel, unfortunately I didn't found anything on internet

Comment: As i said before, having a channel as a medium adds extra complexity. Possible solution is to make your channel private, and remove users whose their subscription expired.(via telegram core api)

Comment: mm seems complicated, I just asked to the author of the membership plugin of wp, and this feature will added in future so I just need to wait, thanks for your reply

Comment: Good to hear that. Good luck:)